# How do you insert current system date and time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert the current system date and time using the following query, when I use `to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF')` I don't get the time.

If i change it to `to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')` I get "not a valid month error"

```
  insert into drv.t_evthst1 (
    vehicle_no,
    business_txn_date,
    business_txn_time,
    business_txn_count,
    part_vehicle_no,
    business_txn,
    bus_txn_appl_rslt,
    act_eps_date,
    act_eps_time,
    business_txn_src,
    event_code,
    event_indicator,
    activity_code,
    fnl_stock_status,
    old_fnl_stock_st,
    coveh_status,
    old_coveh_status,
    damg_status,
    old_damg_status,
    apt_status,
    old_apt_status,
    reg_status,
    old_reg_status,
    consign_status,
    old_consign_status,
    demo_veh_status,
    old_demo_veh_st,
    ordering_status,
    old_ordering_st,
    hold_status,
    old_hold_status,
    ctms_clear_status,
    old_ctms_clear_st,
    invc_status,
    old_invc_st,
    ibmsnap_logmarker,
    created_by,
    created_ts,
    updated_by,
    updated_ts,
    src_sys_id
  )
  values (
    '0004VT9K',
    to_date('31-AUG-18', 'DD-MON-RR'),
    to_date('01-JAN-01', 'DD-MON-RR'),
    8,
    '1',
    'PR01',
    '01',
    to_date('31-AUG-18', 'DD-MON-RR'),
    to_date('01-JAN-01', 'DD-MON-RR'),
    'DREPP750',
    '60',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    '0',
    ' ',
    to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
    'DRVMRSP1',
    to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
    'DRVMRSP1',
    to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
    '1750'
  )
```

> Error starting at line : 3 in command -
>   Error report - ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Please format your code to make it easly readable

Comment: `sysdate` is already a date, you shouldn't manipulate it at all if you're inserting it into a `date` column. And if you're inserting into a `timestamp`-type column, use `systimestamp`.

Comment: when i use systimestamp,ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Why on earth are you storing a DATE values as a `varchar`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i was using to_timestamp() its a timestamp type column, but i was giving it a try

Comment: If the column is a timestamp, then why do you try to store a VARCHAR value in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the relevant columns are defined as `DATE` and/or `TIMESTAMP`, you should not be manipulating the `sysdate` (or `systimestamp`) value at all.

Instead of:

```
...
to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
'DRVMRSP1',
to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
'DRVMRSP1',
to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
'1750'
```

just do:

```
...
sysdate,
'DRVMRSP1',
sysdate,
'DRVMRSP1',
sysdate,
'1750'
```

or

```
...
systimestamp,
'DRVMRSP1',
systimestamp,
'DRVMRSP1',
systimestamp,
'1750'
```

When you use something like this to insert into a date column:

```
to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

you are converting the current date and time to a string (but with a 12-hour time, so you lose any distinction between AM and PM - you'd avoid that with `HH24` instead of `HH`, but that's a side issue). You then do an implicit conversion back to a date, as that's the target column data type, so really you have:

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
```

which uses your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting, so really something like:

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-RR')
```

which will indeed throw "ORA-01843: not a valid month".

Also where you have:

```
to_date('31-AUG-18', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

you are relying on the session language being English, so you should either specify that as part of the `to_date()` call, or use month numbers; and there isn't really any reason to use 2-digit years any more. You can also replace that with an ANSI date literal:

```
date '2018-08-31'
```

It looks like you are sort of splitting the `business_txn_date` and time into two columns, which doesn't really make sense either.

> when I use `to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF')` I don't get the time.

That's also because of the implicit conversion - that is really, again guessing your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, doing:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF') from dual;
```

so you're throwing away the time part in the implicit `to_char()` call, and then `to_timestamp()` is being 'helpful' by treating all the missing components as zeros instead of complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fields in question are of type DATE, and they should be, just insert sysdate.

Answer (score 0):

to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') --> this looks OK,

your error is on LINE 3 then please try completing the year and follow below format:

```
to_date('31-AUG-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```